# mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" when trying to connect

Tags: mysql, systemd

I am trying to do a mysqldump using the following command: `mysqldump -u root -A -R -E --triggers --single-transaction > /home/backups/full_backup_${TODAY}.sql`

**This command runs fine and no error comes when I login and run as a root user**. However, while running it as a daily job using systemd/timers, this command throws an error -

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" when trying to connect

Here are my config details -

I have saved my credentials in `~/.my.cnf` as:

```
[client]
password = "mypassword"

[mysqldump]
user = root
host = localhost
```

permission levels of `/etc/systemd/system/backup.service` and `/etc/systemd/system/backup.timer`

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   90 Nov  5 17:34 backup.service*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  132 Nov 11 10:15 backup.timer*
```

permission levels of `~/.my.cnf`

```
-rw-------  1 root root    76 Nov  5 15:57 .my.cnf
```

permission level of `/home/backups` and `backup.sh` which is executed by `backup.timer` and `backup.service`

```
-rw-------  1 root         root   1872 Nov 11 10:11 backup.sh
drw-------  2 iftvdev      users  4096 Nov 11 10:27 backups/
```

My `backup.timer` file -

```
[Unit]
Description=backup

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 10:17:00
Persistent=true
Unit=backup.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

and `backup.service` file -

```
[Unit]
Description=backup job

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/backup.sh
```

Comment: This might help you: https://serverfault.com/questions/671759/cronjob-executing-mysql-and-get-root-access-denied

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new folder inside my home directory and passed `defaults-extra-file` with my `mysqldump` command and it worked.

This fixed it - https://serverfault.com/questions/671759/cronjob-executing-mysql-and-get-root-access-denied